# Retrieving Bitmap from Redirected URL

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am using the following void method to get a Bitmap image from a URL:

```
public static Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
        final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
        final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
            final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
                Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url); 
                return null;
            }

            final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = entity.getContent(); 
                    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    return bitmap;
                } finally {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();  
                    }
                    entity.consumeContent();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException or IllegalStateException
            getRequest.abort();
            Log.e("ImageDownloader", "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
        } finally {
            if (client != null) {
                client.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The most common URL I feed with this method is this: http://graph.facebook.com/+FACEBOOK_USER_ID+/picture, but this URL redirects to http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v2/y9/r/xxxxx.gif. That’s why I’m not getting the Bitmap image, what I’m getting is an error related to a 302 Redirect. 
How do I handle redirected URLs, and get the Bitmap file?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just request the image URL and fetch it directly?

intead of `https://graph.facebook.com/[object id]/picture`

request
`https://graph.facebook.com/[object id]?fields=picture`

Comment: `https://graph.facebook.com/[object id]?fields=picture` returns `JSON`. So instead of fetching it directly, I will to parse the `JSON` first to get the exact URL. Nice suggestion though! :)

Answer (score -1):

you need to append ?type=large in URL to get the picture...

e.g following code shows how to get on imageview...

> ImageView user_picture;
>
> userpicture=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.userpicture);
>
> URL img_value = null;
>
> img_value = new
>   URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=large");
>
> Bitmap mIcon1 =
>   BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
>
> userpicture.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);

Try adding **?type=large** in URL and let me know your result.